# Can't see Animation Modifiers tab?

Tags: animation

I can't see the modifiers tab in the graph editor...

When I press N it just brings up a blank panel. I have the animation selected for sure, plus I tried toggling the animation edit-ability. No luck. If anybody knows how to fix this, please help. Thank you. :)

[image]

Comment: You have to select the channel or key frames you want to apply the modifiers to.

Comment: @susu I have and it's not showing, thank you though. :)

Comment: @susu I've added an image of what I'm seeing. The smaller red selected parts are to show that I have the animation selected, and the bigger red selected part is where the modifier screen should be. :)

Comment: @susu Unfortunately I can't share it as it contains some private info.

Comment: @susu I would but that'd be very difficult, plus some of it is in the animation itself.

Comment: That's not the graph editor, it's the dope sheet. Put the area into graph editor.

Comment: @batFINGER Oh my I'm so blind... tysm lol, it's fixed now! :)

Comment: @batFINGER you should put that comment into an answer so OP can accept it. I came here searching for the same problem and that was the solution.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for are "*F-Curve Modifiers*", not "*Animation Modifiers*". It's interesting to remember that name precisely, because it tells you what it is and where to find it:

Modifiers on animation curves. Where do you manage animation curves? In the **Graph Editor**:

[image: Graph Editor]

[F-Curve Modifiers — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/graph_editor/fcurves/modifiers.html)

Besides, "animation modifier" could be understood as something that can be put on multiple curves or even objects or entire action strips. It sounds cool, but it's not an existing in Blender. At least, not yet ...